# How does Hibernate query on a column with @ManyToOne relationship?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I was wondering, How does hibernate query the table internally when we query on a column which is foreign key. Please see the code for more understanding

Employee Table

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
  @Id
  private String userId;
  
  private String name;
    
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
  @JoinTable(
    name = "employee_department",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "department_code")
  
  private Department department;
    
}
```

Department Table

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Department{
  
  @Id
  @Column(name = "code", unique = true)
  private String code;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

}
```

So once the application is deployed, we will have three tables i.e. `employee`, `department` and `employee_department`. Now if I write hibernate like
`findByDepartmentCodeIn(Department Code)` , How will hibernate internally parse this query ? I want to create an index on column `department_code` to make the former query faster so where do I create an index, in the `department` table or in the resulting merger `employee_department` table ?

Comment: From your Entity model, an Employee would belong to one Department, I am trying to understand why would you require a join table?. Can't you just have the department_id column in the employee table?. You might require join table when an employee can be part of multiple department.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your `application.properties`

`spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

It will show all the query u have made.